# Extract the stream from a Silverlight image control

Tags: silverlight

Is it possible to extract the steam (or something similar) from a silverlight image control?

I figured you could get the stream from the Image.Source property, but so far that has been a dead end option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the answer is no. The reason being that the image element is not constrained by the same cross-domain limitations that most other network traffic is subjected to in Silverlight (i.e. you can display an image accessed cross-domain, but your application can never access the image data).

In order to get access to the underlying bits of an Image, you can get the image's source URI and then use WebClient to request the stream (assuming that your app has the appropriate access to that server).

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that I am setting the Image.Source via streams I generate, but I guess a viable solution will be to simply hold on to a copy of the stream in a local variable.